# VBA: Iterate through an associative array (Dictionary) and print Key and Value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a collection object in VBA with key and value and I'd like to iterate through them and display them in debug console.

**Here is my code:**

```
    ' Generated error code array
    Dim errCodeArr As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim ItemKey As Variant

    Set rsErrCodes = dbQuery("select errorcode from tbl_errorcodes order by errorcode")

    On Error GoTo arrErr
    While Not rsErrCodes.EOF
        errCodeArr.Add rsErrCodes!errorCode, rsErrCodes!errorCode & "filler"
        rsErrCodes.MoveNext
    Wend

    For Each ItemKey In errCodeArr
        Debug.Print "Key: " & ItemKey
        Debug.Print "Value: " & errCodeArr.Item(ItemKey)
    Next

    arrErr:
       Debug.Print err.Description
```

**Error Description:**
This key is already associated with an element of this collection

I've changed to question to reflect the changes, but now I'm getting a key error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know it isn't possible with Collections, but possible with Dictionaries:

```
Dim errCodeArr As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim ItemKey As Variant

Set rsErrCodes = dbQuery("select errorcode from tbl_errorcodes order by errorcode")

On Error GoTo arrErr
While Not rsErrCodes.EOF
    errCodeArr.Add CStr(rsErrCodes!errorCode), CStr(rsErrCodes!errorCode & "filler")
    rsErrCodes.MoveNext
Wend

For Each ItemKey In errCodeArr
    Debug.Print "Key: " & ItemKey
    Debug.Print "Value: " & errCodeArr.Item(ItemKey)
Next
```

You can read about usnig Dictionary in Excel [here](http://www.techbookreport.com/tutorials/vba_dictionary.html)

Comment: That didn't work. I've posted the changes to the question. Can you have a look and let me know what might be wrong?

Comment: error occurs because you have tried to add too or more values with equals keys (`errCodeArr.Add rsErrCodes!errorCode, rsErrCodes!errorCode & "filler"`). Keys must be unique.

Comment: The key is unique. Here is the output: `Before add: 00454 => 00454filler Before add: 00455 => 00455filler This key is already associated with an element of this collection`. When it goes to add the second one "00455" it fails. That's different from "00454". How are these two keys the same?

Comment: Try to modify your line of code: `errCodeArr.Add rsErrCodes!errorCode, rsErrCodes!errorCode & "filler"` to `errCodeArr.Add CStr(rsErrCodes!errorCode), CStr(rsErrCodes!errorCode & "filler")`

Comment: LOL I just found the answer somewhere else and came back here to post it and looks like you posted the same thing. Yup that worked. It was storing an Object for the Key, no it's storing a string. Works. I'll give you vote up and correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your answer to reflect the changes? So the answer is correct for the answer you gave in your comment. Thanks!